# Are the following sentences grammtically correct

Tags: grammar

Hello I don't know if the following sentences are grammatically correct

1. It's weird **how** we aren't on the same time.
2. It's weird **that** we aren't on the same team.
3. I like **how** you can fly
4. I like **that** you can fly

Answer (score 1):

1. This sentence doesn't break a grammatical rule, however it has an ambiguous meaning.  Does it refer to the weirdness of the international time system countries have agreed upon, or simply to the fact that we're not on the same time?  You can't tell.
2. This sentence is not only grammatically correct but also has a clearer meaning.
3. Again, not wrong, but ambiguous in a similar way. Do you like that I can fly in a certain way, or simply the fact that I can fly?  If you mean the former, a better way to phrase it would be simply, "I like how you fly."
4. Once again, this sentence is better.

I hope that helps.